# .htaccess error pages outside of domain root directory

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, error-handling

I chave an .htaccess file that calls the error.php file located in the domain root directory. However, **I want to apply the error handling to many different directories all within the same directory but the root directory isn't a domain directory.
How can I do this?**

Currently my .htaccess file looks like this...

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
ErrorDocument 400 /error.php?t=400
ErrorDocument 401 /error.php?t=401
ErrorDocument 403 /error.php?t=403
ErrorDocument 404 /error.php?t=404
ErrorDocument 500 /error.php?t=500
ErrorDocument 503 /error.php?t=503
```

(I hope you can understand what I'm trying to describe)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have the file wherever you want it, and symlink it to the specific directories.

.htaccess *cannot* have an effect on anything outside the document root.

Comment: How can I do that? Sorry, I'm a bit of a newbie.

Comment: Say you have /var/www/domain1 as the document root and the error page at /var/www/common. The command (*nix) would be `ln -s /var/www/common/error.php /var/www/domain1/error.php`

Comment: Okay, so how could I tie this in with an ErrorDocument?

Comment: The ErrorDocument directives in the .htaccess would not change. You are basically making a shortcut to error.php inside the document root.